# Azure Storage Explorer Query where by Timestamp

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-storage

it's my first time working with Azure Storage Explorer and I need to read some logs that is save into Azure Tables. The version of mine is 4

I read this reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ff683669.aspx but there is not explanation to work with the column Timestamp.

Basically, I want to see logs since a specific date.

I tried query like;

**Timestamp ge '4/10/2013'
Timestamp ge 4/10/2013
Timestamp gt '4/10/2013'

Timestamp gt 4/10/2013**

***And the result is only a error message.***

**An error occurred while processing this request.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you would need to use something like below in order to filter on a Timestamp. Please look at Filtering on DateTime Properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ff683669.aspx).

Timestamp ge datetime'2008-07-10T00:00:00Z'

Comment: how can i get the latest record?

Answer (score 3):

Use `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate()` methods to set datetime based query parameters against Azure table storage tables:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

// Input parameters to your method, etc:
DateTimeOffset from;
DateTimeOffset until;

string DateFromFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Date", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, from);
string DateUntilFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Date", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, until);
```

`finalFilter` is just a string which you build up using **TableQuery** methods such as `CombineFilters()`:

```
finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(finalFilter, TableOperators.And, DateFromFilter);
finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(finalFilter, TableOperators.And, DateUntilFilter);

TableQuery<MyAzureObject> query = new TableQuery<MyAzureObject>().Where(finalFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do it:

```
var dateFilter = "(PartitionKey ge '0" + StartTime.Ticks + "')" + "and (PartitionKey le '0" + EndTime.Ticks + "')";
```

`StartTime` and `EndTime` will be your date range. Remember that you can only query over PartitionKey because it has index.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

`Timestamp ge datetime'2013-10-06T00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the query in the date range use:

```
Timestamp ge datetime'2017-07-21T20:07:35.000Z' and Timestamp lt datetime'2017-07-24T20:07:35.000Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

its old but I got this working like this.

```
Timestamp ge datetime'2020-10-06T00:00:00'
```